# Entity Framework CheckboxList Database Insert

Tags: entity-framework, foreign-keys, checkboxlist

UPDATED:

I'm using a Detailsview Insert Control and I am trying to create a new row in the database from a checkbox in a CheckBoxList.  I'm getting the "The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint"

Here is my cs:

```
  protected void AddPrincipleStaffDetailsView_ItemInserting(object sender, DetailsViewInsertEventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBoxList PrincipleStaffTitle = (CheckBoxList)FindControl("PrincipleStaffTitle");

        if (PrincipleStaffTitle != null)
        {
            foreach (ListItem item in PrincipleStaffTitle.Items)
            {
                if (item.Selected)
                {

                    string stringSession = Session["ProductionID"].ToString();
                    int intProductionID = Int32.Parse(stringSession);

                    var ID = item.Value;



                    using (var context = new FactoryTheaterModelFirstContainer())
                    {
                        PrincipleStaff principlestaff = new PrincipleStaff();

                        principlestaff.PrincipleStaffTitle = ID;
                        principlestaff.Production_proProductionID = intProductionID;

                        context.PrincipleStaffs.Add(principlestaff);
                        context.SaveChanges();
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

here is the aspx:

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="PrincipleStaffSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="name=FactoryTheaterModelFirstContainer" DefaultContainerName="FactoryTheaterModelFirstContainer" EnableFlattening="False" EntitySetName="PrincipleStaffs" EntityTypeFilter="PrincipleStaff" EnableInsert="True"></asp:EntityDataSource>
<asp:DetailsView ID="AddPrincipleStaffDetailsView" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" DataKeyNames="PrincipleStaffID" DataSourceID="PrincipleStaffSource" Height="50px" Width="730px" DefaultMode="Insert" OnItemInserting="AddPrincipleStaffDetailsView_ItemInserting" OnItemInserted="AddPrincipleStaffDetailsView_ItemInserted">
    <Fields>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Add Principle Staff Role:" SortExpression="PrincipleStaffTitle">
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBoxList ID="PrincipleStaffTitle" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("PrincipleStaffTitle") %>'>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Director">Director(s)</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Assistant Director">Assistant Director(s)</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Written By">Written By(s)</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Executive Producer">Executive Producer(s)</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Producer">Producer(s)</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Techincal Director">Technical Director(s)</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:CheckBoxList>
            </InsertItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PrincipleStaffTitle") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:CommandField ShowInsertButton="True" />
    </Fields>
</asp:DetailsView>
```

The Production.proProductionID is the foreign key that I'm trying to get into the PrincipleStaff Production_proProductionid column.  I can't seem to create the FK relationship.

Thanks for any help that can be provided!

Comment: Why are you using tow dbContext instances here? Can you post code for your two related entities as well?

Comment: Thanks Jayantha.  I've updated code to use only 1 db instance.  That was my last ditch effort when I posted code but I think this is closer to what it should look like.  I'm wondering if I'm having a problem with a parent/child relationship here.

Comment: Yes may be. Can u post your two related entities as well?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the two related entities.  The tables I have are Production and Principle Staff.  The Production table is the parent table with a one to many relationship.  The Production_proProductionID field in the PrincipleStaff table (PrincipleStaffs entity) is the foreign key from the Production table proProductionID column.  This may all be due to my lack of full understanding of EF although I'm learning a lot and hopefully my terminology is correct.  Also - I'm using the Database First Model.

Comment: After some troubleshooting - I am finding that my asp:checkboxlist is returning null.  
    CheckBoxList PrincipleStaffTitle = (CheckBoxList)FindControl("PrincipleStaffTitle");

        if (PrincipleStaffTitle != null)

Answer (score 0):

The Below code works.  I've since moved my context.savechanges(); outside the loop.  My issue was happening on my ItemInserted command.

```
protected void AddPrincipleStaffDetailsView_ItemInserting(object sender, DetailsViewInsertEventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBoxList PrincipleStaffCheckBox = (CheckBoxList)AddPrincipleStaffDetailsView.FindControl("PrincipleStaffTitleCheckBoxList");

        if (PrincipleStaffCheckBox.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (ListItem item in PrincipleStaffCheckBox.Items)
            {
                if (item.Selected)
                {

                    string stringSession = Session["ProductionID"].ToString();
                    int intProductionID = 0;
                    intProductionID = Int32.Parse(stringSession);
                    var principlestafftitle = item.Value;

                        try
                        {
                            using (var context = new FactoryTheaterModelFirstContainer())
                            {

                                Production proid = context.Productions.Single(i => i.proProductionID == intProductionID);
                                PrincipleStaff principlestaff = new PrincipleStaff()
                                {
                                    PrincipleStaffTitle = principlestafftitle,
                                    Production_proProductionID = intProductionID
                                };

                                proid.PrincipleStaffs.Add(principlestaff);
                                context.SaveChanges();
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception f)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(f); // or log to file, etc.
                            throw; // re-throw the exception if you want it to continue up the stack
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```